# Group By and Create an Column Index in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rowid

I have a data set of users who attempt a set of math problems. They are randomly given a hint(s) to solve the problem (hint.flag). I want to find out how soon a user gets the "correct" answer (Correctness) for each problem after seeing the FIRST hint within a problem. To begin with I would need to create some kind of index to identify which post hint attempt they are on.

```
data.input <- read_table2("user.id  problem.id  correctness hint.flag
540995  A   FALSE   1
540995  A   FALSE   0
540995  A   FALSE   1
540995  B   FALSE   1
540995  B   FALSE   1
540995  B   TRUE    0
540995  C   FALSE   1
540995  C   FALSE   1
540995  C   TRUE    0
540995  D   TRUE    0
565662  A   TRUE    0
565662  A   FALSE   1
565662  A   FALSE   0
565662  A   FALSE   1
565662  A   FALSE   1
565662  A   FALSE   0
565662  A   FALSE   0
565662  A   FALSE   0")
```

The column I am trying to impute is "post.hint.attempt" (see desired.output).

```
desired.output <- read_table2("user.id  problem.id  correctness hint.flag   post.hint.attempt

540995  A   FALSE   1   
540995  A   FALSE   0   first
540995  A   FALSE   1   second
540995  B   FALSE   1   
540995  B   FALSE   1   first
540995  B   TRUE    0   second
540995  C   FALSE   1   
540995  C   FALSE   1   first
540995  C   TRUE    0   second
540995  D   TRUE    0   
565662  A   TRUE    0   
565662  A   FALSE   1   
565662  A   FALSE   0   first
565662  A   FALSE   1   second
565662  A   FALSE   1   third
565662  A   FALSE   0   fourth
565662  A   FALSE   0   fifth
565662  A   FALSE   0   sixth 
")
```

I have no idea how to even begin finding this... I think row_id might be useful, but the need to lag the attempt number by the occurrence of a hint is confusing to me. Any help would be amazing!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case, here is another approach with `tidyverse`. It involves checking the `row_number` within a given problem, and add a counter value if it comes after the first hint. A cumulative sum of this counter is then added.

(Note you will get a warning if a problem does not have any hints.)

```
library(tidyverse)

data.input %>%
  group_by(user.id, problem.id) %>%
  mutate(count = ifelse(row_number() > min(which(hint.flag == 1)), 1, 0),
         post.hint.attempt = cumsum(count)) %>%
  select(-count)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 18 x 5
# Groups:   user.id, problem.id [5]
   user.id problem.id correctness hint.flag post.hint.attempt
     <dbl> <chr>      <lgl>           <dbl>             <dbl>
 1  540995 A          FALSE               1                 0
 2  540995 A          FALSE               0                 1
 3  540995 A          FALSE               1                 2
 4  540995 B          FALSE               1                 0
 5  540995 B          FALSE               1                 1
 6  540995 B          TRUE                0                 2
 7  540995 C          FALSE               1                 0
 8  540995 C          FALSE               1                 1
 9  540995 C          TRUE                0                 2
10  540995 D          TRUE                0                 0
11  565662 A          TRUE                0                 0
12  565662 A          FALSE               1                 0
13  565662 A          FALSE               0                 1
14  565662 A          FALSE               1                 2
15  565662 A          FALSE               1                 3
16  565662 A          FALSE               0                 4
17  565662 A          FALSE               0                 5
18  565662 A          FALSE               0                 6
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not your desired output, but you might want to consider it as an option

```
data.example %>% 
group_by(user.id, problem.id) %>%
 mutate(total_hints = cumsum(hint.flag), trial=1:n()) %>%
 summarise(hints = last(total_hints),
 trials = last(trial),
 correct = last(correctness))
```

which produces

```
# Groups:   user.id [2]
  user.id problem.id hints trials correct
    <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>  <int> <lgl>  
1  540995 A              2      3 FALSE  
2  540995 B              2      3 TRUE   
3  540995 C              2      3 TRUE   
4  540995 D              0      1 TRUE   
5  565662 A              3      8 FALSE
```

## Update

Is this closer?
First create a key, then bind and do math

```
key <- data.example %>% group_by(user.id, problem.id) %>% mutate(trial=1:n()) %>% filter(hint.flag == 1) %>%
rename(hint_trial = trial)
```

```
left_join(data.example, key) %>% 
group_by(user.id, problem.id) %>%
 mutate(trial=1:n(),
 target = trial - first(hint_trial))
```

Comment: ---the variable I am trying to impute is post.hint.attempt. I'll edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: @NewBee Maybe include your expected result for the provided data set

Comment: I've added the desired output!

Comment: ,. Thanks for offering an answer. It's helpful, but not quite what I need...I need to identify the exact attempt they got the answer right.